# Locate the nodes in the shader editor

Tags: node-editor

I move around in shader editor panel and become too far away from the nodes. I tried to go back to the nodes but can not find them. Any method or hot key to locate nodes in the shader editor “Black Sea”?

Answer (score 2):

Press the <kbd>Home</kbd> key to show all nodes.

Comment: ... with the shaded object selected. Obvious, but I've lost mine that way. Like losing my spectacles whe they're riding on top of my head :)

Answer (score 0):

Method 1: Press <kbd>F3</kbd> then type in: "Find Nodes"

Method 2: In Shading editor panel *Select > Find Nodes*